# Is it possible to block push upgrades from managed packages?

Tags: managed-package, isv

We are having some issues introduced by one package from Eloqua, the app was upgraded automatically and it has caused a couple of serious issues.

Is there a way to block this automatic upgrades and 'approve' them or have the choice to do it manually?. Or should we ask Eloqua to exclude our org from those automatic pushes?

Comment: trigger on one of their objects that would fail if Test.isRunningTest()? ;)

Comment: Yeah, some of the assertions in their test methods are failing. It has also caused conflict with another integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but perhaps you could set a recurring Apex schedule task to run that does nothing but access an object in the package, or somehow connects to another aspect of it. I know that if you have scheduled Apex who's code is contained in a package, that the package can't upgrade until you stop the scheduled Apex.

Might be worth a shot.

EDIT:

Per kibitzer's suggestion, I'd go to Name|Setup|Develop|Apex Classes and look for the Security link next to any class that belongs to the Eloqua package:

[image]

These classes are global and if referenced by a scheduled class, this *should* prevent them from doing a push-upgrade.

Comment: Interesting workaround, hard to test though. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea. You may be able to get this to work if the package has any global class. You can create you own scheduleable class, and in its constructor create an instance of the global object. The Apex schedular holds an instance of your class which holds an instance of the other global class. That could block the upgrade.

Comment: Good point, kibitzer. If Eloqua happens to have any batch Apex, they'll have at least one global class. And even if creating an instance of the class isn't feasible or proves challenging, just referencing it should work.

Comment: I guess that official "good" way is just ask Eloqua to push your org id into their exclusion list